# error : interleave() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deterministic', when using tensorflow_datasets

Tags: tensorflow2.0, interleave

Hei, error happens when using and processing dataset from tfds.

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
cifar_builder = tfds.builder("cifar100")
cifar_builder.download_and_prepare()

print(cifar_builder.info)
train_cifar_dataset = cifar_builder.as_dataset(split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)

**TypeError: interleave() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deterministic'**

Many thanks if someone can give some hints.